# Change Image when href is active

Tags: html, css

I might have done this the wrong way. I've made a navigation bar with 4 images that link to some other pages. The navigation bar is on every page as it should be. I can hover over the image to change the source, but I also want to change the source if I am on a specific page.

For example, when I click on 'shopping cart', my site navigates me out to that page and the navigation bar looks the exact same. I want the image that I clicked to change to a different image, **only** when I'm on that page. If I go to a different page, I want the image to return to it's original state. The user should be able to see all 4 images, and the 'shopping cart' one is the only one that looks different, implying that they are on the shopping cart page

Basically, I'm looking for something like what Twitter has done. (Image changes when you on 'Home' page and when you are on 'Connect' page).

I've tried the :active and the :focus class and those don't work for me. Maybe I need some Javascript? I'm honestly not sure. I've searched google up and down. I would appreciate any help, even if it is just new documentation that I can test.

Anything! Thanks :)

```
html:
 <nav>
<ulstyle="list-style-type:none">
<li id="daily_sale" style="display:inline"><a href="/DealOfTheDay.asp?deal="></a></li>
<li id="my_account" style="display:inline"><a href="/login.asp"></a></li>
<li id="support" style="display:inline"><a href="/terms.asp"></a></li>
<li id="shopping_cart" style="display:inline"><a href="/shoppingcart.asp"></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: where's the code. how can we help if you don't provide the problem

Comment: you can use css classes for the purpose. Since nav bar is available in all pages, use classes in the appropriate page suitably.

Comment: I've added my code. I have the class written out. I think what I want to do is add a class if the url is one of these. I've searched up and down and tried a couple of different JS functions, but none seem to work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

What are your pages built with?  WordPress?  PHP?  Static html pages?

Ideally, you would add a class to the nav bar item that you are currently on.  For example, if you are on the Home page, add a class of "active" to your list item.

Then you can add CSS for the active class to change the background image.

Comment: my pages are static html/asp. I do have a class that each href is contained in, and each href has its own class also (so I can identify A from B and so on)

Answer (score 1):

You can use location.href property in javascript to detect the current page, and add some additional CSS class to corresponding menu item.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this property (or welled versed in javascript), but I will start doing some research on this. Thanks!